# IF statement in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, report

I am struggling with the syntax of getting an if statement or case statement in an order by clause.

Here is my current code:

```
order by 
    case WHEN (col.line_item_no != 0) THEN Parent_Catalog_Desc,
                 col.line_no, spc.attr_value, col.line_item_no ELSE
       Parent_Catalog_Desc, col.line_no END
```

Says I am missing a keyword.  Let me know if you need more context.

Basically, if the line_item_no field is NOT 0, it follows that first sort order, if it IS 0, i use a different sort order.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor out the first two columns.  Then use a `CASE` for the remaining columns:

```
order by Parent_Catalog_Desc, col.line_no,
         (CASE WHEN col.line_item_no <> 0 THEN spc.attr_value END),
         (CASE WHEN col.line_item_no <> 0 THEN col.line_item_no END)
```

`CASE` is an expression in a SQL statement that returns a single value.  Hence it cannot be used to return multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` statement only returns a single value. You can't have a comma-delimited list within it as you do. You can try concatenating the values, but then you need to worry about mixing data types and how combining strings with numerics can mess up ordering. The other possibility is to use multiple `CASE` statements, like so:

```
ORDER BY
    parent_catalog_desc,
    col.line_no,
    CASE WHEN COL.line_item_no != 0 THEN spc.attr_value ELSE 0 END
    CASE WHEN COL.line_item_no != 0 THEN col.line_item_no ELSE 0 END
```